# error: too many arguments to function

Tags: c, serial-port, raspberry-pi, lcd

I am working on a project that uses non standard `C` Libraries to display the output on an LCD screen. I have the code working great but I have run into a problem.

What my intended purpose of this program is to do is take a command line string of text and convert it to the ASCII decimal values then display them on the screen. The way that you output text to the screen is by making a call to the `serialPutchar` function so to display the letter `H` I would write it as `serialPutchar(fd, 'H');` I want to be able to get the values from variables and output the letters in the variable.

The problem is that when I write it as `serialPutchar(fd, "%c", H);` or try `serialPutchar(fd, "%d", x);` I get the following error:

```
testing.c: In function âmainâ:
testing.c:22:3: warning: passing argument 1 of âserialPutcharâ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/usr/local/include/wiringSerial.h:30:14: note: expected âintâ but argument is of type âchar *â
testing.c:22:3: error: too many arguments to function âserialPutcharâ
/usr/local/include/wiringSerial.h:30:14: note: declared here
```

I'm guessing it cant be used in that fashion like you would use `printf` so is there an alternative to this or maybe I just have a simple error I am not spotting. I am including a link to the documentation for the `wiringSerial` library. Also from my error output I am getting the strange characters around the error `testing.c In function main:` and several other lines. Is there a way to prevent this?  Link to library [HERE](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/serial-library/) Below is my working code to output `HELLO`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int fd ;
  if ((fd = serialOpen ("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600)) < 0)
  {
    fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open serial device: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
    return 1 ;
  }

  if (wiringPiSetup () == -1)
  {
    fprintf (stdout, "Unable to start wiringPi: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
    return 1 ;
  }
    int H = 1;
         serialPutchar(fd, 'H');
         serialPutchar(fd, 'E');
         serialPutchar(fd, 'L');
         serialPutchar (fd, 'L');
         serialPutchar (fd, 'O');
  }
```

:::UPDATE:::

Here is the working code that fit my description:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int fd ;
  if ((fd = serialOpen ("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600)) < 0)
  {
    fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open serial device: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
    return 1 ;
  }

  if (wiringPiSetup () == -1)
  {
    fprintf (stdout, "Unable to start wiringPi: %s\n", strerror (errno)) ;
    return 1 ;
  }
        for (int i=1; i<argc; i++){
         serialPrintf (fd, "%s",  argv[i]);
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

putChar takes a char as its second argument.   Not a string, not a format string with arguments, just a char.

If you have a char in a variable x, just do:

```
 serialPutchar(fd, x);
```

Comment: As a helpful follow-up for the OP, take a look at "void  serialPuts (int fd, char *s) ;" - you can use the standard library function sprintf to still have formatting, then write that entire string with the serialPuts function. Good luck!

Comment: @RonDahlgren would you please provide an example on how to use that function or possibly the `serialPrintf` function I am relatively new to programming